# Getting Error while adding Parse FCM library Error: Program type already present: com.parse.AbstractQueryController$1

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I want to add push notification.I am referring this [link](https://jitpack.io/#parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/1.18.1) To do the same I am adding below dependencies:

implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.18.5'

implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse-android:1.17.2'

I have  clean, Invalidate Cache and re-build my project. But when I run the project I get the above error.